# This class is not key value code compliant for the key dateLabel

Tags: ios

My program crashes with the following error, I have tried to resolve but couldn't solve this issue. 
This is my code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Load the nib file
    UINib *nib=[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BNRCourseDetailCell" bundle:nil];

    //Register nib
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BNRCourseDetailCell"];
}



 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BNRCourseDetailCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BNRCourseDetailCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *course=self.courses[indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *details=[course[@"upcoming"] objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.titleLable.text=course[@"title"];
    if (details)
    {
        cell.dateLabel.text= details[@"start_date"];
        cell.instructorLabel.text=details[@"instructors"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.dateLabel.text= @"TBA";
        cell.instructorLabel.text=@"TBA";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

My Error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x8d4dfa0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dateLabel.'
```

Any Help will appreciated. Thanks

Comment: check for all outlet names and connect it properly

Comment: @user3575357 your customcell dateLabel IBOutlet is not connected so connect with your xib to that outlet .

Comment: Thanks for your responses, my problem was solved as I followed the instructions of Prathamesh saraf.

Answer (score 0):

Making it a little picturesque [image]

and then

[image]

Remember , you would need

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
```

In your custom class .h file. This should fix it

Comment: I'd give +1 for your effort with the pictures, very nice! But unfortunately you're missing the point: there already _is_ a connection, but the target class doesn't have the variable/property (any more).

Comment: Thanks DarkDust for the appreciation. Theres a catch here, and its based on my observations. Please try and bear my explanation. If the "File's Owner" class is set to the custom class , despite the fact that the IBOutlet is connected it will still through the same error(as of now, beyond my comprehension).I have faced this in a couple of my projects. I am suspecting that he has set the File's Owners custom class and not the Tableview cells' Custom Class as i have shown in the images.

Comment: So in a nutshell, you'd like to say that he made the connection to the wrong object (_File's Owner_ instead of _Table View Cell_), is that right? But Interface Builder won't let you make the connection if the target class doesn't have such an `IBOutlet` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you helped me out of this misery. That was a good picture explanation. Thank you very much

Comment: @DarkDust : yes , you got it right. Yes thats true. but i believe he has the outlet in the target class since he is registering a nib. user3575357 : please remove all connections of outlets, Files Owners Custom class should be blank (NSObject as placeholder). and follow my answer. It will work.

Comment: Glad to be of some help. Can you please accept it if it solved your issue? :) .

Answer (score 0):

In your `BNRCourseDetailCell.xib` (most likely), there's a connection to an `IBOutlet` variable or property called `dateLabel`. However, when the XIB is loaded, that variable or property doesn't exist on the target class.

This can happen for example if you had such a variable/property, made the connection, and then deleted the variable/property from the class. In this case you need to remove this connection from the XIB as well. It can also happen if you change the class of an item in your XIB to another class that doesn't have that variable/property.

Unfortunately the exception doesn't tell us the name of the target class, so it's a bit of guessing on your part. I like to search the XIB (which is just an XML file) directly in cases like these to find the connection(s) (but do the modification in Interface Builder).